# How to design the reward for an action which is the only legal action at some state

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am working on an RL project, but got stuck at one point: The task is continuous (Non-episodic). Following some suggestion from Sutton's [RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/bookdraft2017nov5.pdf), I am using a value function approximation method with average reward (differential return instead of discount return). For some state (represented by some features), only one action is legal. I am not sure how to design a reward for such action. Is it ok to just assign the reward in the previous step? Or assign the average reward (take the average of all reward collected so far)？ Could anyone tell me the best way to decide the reward for the only legal action? Thank you!

UPDATE:
To give more details, I added one simplified example:
Let me explain this by a simplified example: the state space consists of a job queue with fix size and a single server. The queue state is represented by the duration of jobs and the server state is represented by the time left to finish the currently running job.  When the queue is not full and the server is idle, the agent can SCHEDULE a job to the server for execution and see a state transition(taking next job into the queue) or the agent can TAKE NEXT JOB into the queue. But when the job queue is full and the server is still running a job, the agent can do nothing except take a BLOCKING action and witness a state transit (time left to finish running job gets decreased by one unit time). The BLOCKING action is the only action that the agent can take in that state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designing the reward is part of the problem setup. Do you want to encourage the agent to get into states where the only action is BLOCKING? Or should it avoid such states?

There can be no correct answer without knowing your optimization goal. It doesn't have anything to do with how many legal actions the agent has. It also doesn't have to do anything with value functions. The decision is equally important if you train your agent via random search or a GA directly in the policy space.

A different problem is how to deal with invalid actions during learning. If the "BLOCKING" action can only be taken in a state where there are no other decisions, then you could re-design the environment such that it automatically skips over those states. It would have to accumulate all the rewards for the "no decision" states and give them as a combined reward for the last real decision, and present the agent with the next real decision. If you are using discounted rewards you'd have to take the discounting factor into account too, in order to not modify the cost function that the agent is optimizing.

Another way to deal with invalid actions is to make the agent learn to avoid them. You see this in most gridworld examples: when the agent tries to move into a wall, it just doesn't happen. Some default action happens instead. The reward function is then structured such that it will always yield a worse return (e.g. more steps or negative reward). The only disadvantage is that this requires extra exploration. The function approximator faces a more difficult task; it needs enough capacity and more data to recognize that in some states, some actions have a different effect.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it would be good if such state is avoided. But such state is a possible situation the agent has to deal with. I am using average reward (defined in Sutton's book Chapter10.3) instead of discount reward. I would appreciate if you could provide more insight.

Comment: The agent itself (that is, the policy) has no problem here. The value function doesn't even need to be defined or evaluated in states with only a single action. Using the definition of the return, you can calculate a new value approximation using e.g. using two rewards and the value function two steps ahead.

Comment: I've added a section about learning to avoid invalid actions. Although I'm not quite sure if I understood why you are asking; maybe I'm just stating the obvious now.